# GroupBy X returning multiple records/rows for X

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following logic.

```
SELECT  min(Value1),
    UNIQUE_Identifier 
FROM    panel
WHERE (some criteria = 'x')
GROUP BY UNIQUE_Identifier
```

When I import the results/flat file into Excel, there are multiple rows with the same Unique-Identifier its associated value.  Am I I missing something?  Shouldn't the select min and Group By give me ONE Value for each distinct Unique Identifier?

One update.  The data type of the Unique Identifier is numeric.  Also, Unique_Identifiers look like this: 1000137210003040.  When I paste 1000137210003040 or   1000137210003047 into Excel, they both come back as 1000137210003040.

Comment: Something else must be going on that impacts your result.

Comment: Hi can you provide details about your structure, what is the type of `UNIQUE_Identifier` is it `varchar` ? you checked the `UNIQUE_Identifier` values ? there is any space or difference between returned `UNIQUE_Identifier` ?

Comment: UNIQUE_Identifier's data type is numeric.

Comment: This is a question about Excel, not SQL. Database has correct data, but when you paste it into Excel it rounds it. Apparently, these numbers are too big for Excel. Try to paste then into Excel as text, not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Excel is importing the data as a number.  The number is represented as a floating point number, and trailing digits are rounded.  I think Excel keeps 15 digits of precision.

One way you can force a string is to turn the value into a string in the query:

```
SELECT  min(Value1), 'UQ' || UNIQUE_Identifier 
FROM    panel
WHERE (some criteria = 'x')
GROUP BY UNIQUE_Identifier;
```

Also, prepending with a single quote also often works:

```
SELECT  min(Value1), '''' || UNIQUE_Identifier 
FROM    panel
WHERE (some criteria = 'x')
GROUP BY UNIQUE_Identifier;
```

Or wrapping the value in double quotes:

```
SELECT  min(Value1), '"' || UNIQUE_Identifier || '"'
FROM    panel
WHERE (some criteria = 'x')
GROUP BY UNIQUE_Identifier;
```

Which works best may depend on how you bring the data into Excel.

Comment: What do the "||" mean?

Comment: @ZJAY . . . That is a string concatenation operator.

Comment: @ZJAY: see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL